# Cakephp doesn't write a cookie

Tags: php, cakephp, cookies

I have a problem with writing cookies in cakephp and even don't know how to debug it or where too look for a clue.

I've inherited a project where cookie were only created using the Session component, of course i added 'Cookie' to $components array in app_controller and put this in beforeFilter:

```
$this->Cookie->name = 'foo';
$this->Cookie->path = '/home/~nick'; 
$this->Cookie->domain = 'hostname';   
$this->Cookie->secure = false;  //i.e. only sent if using secure HTTPS
$this->Cookie->key = 'some key';
```

and in some action i use:

```
$this->Cookie->write('key', 'value');
```

I access page by http://hostname/home/~nick/foo and actually try to put even something so silly. I doesn't work.
I would be really gratefully for any clue where to search problem.
Thanks!

Comment: ok, i have one clue, setting domain to '' helped, but i don't know why previous setting didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your domain value was probably wrong making the cookie unavailable. Leaving it blank probably defaults to the current domain.

Comment: Thanks, during the deployment i'll try setting different domains (localhost, vhosts etc.) and see what is happening.